# How to access objects dynamically?

Tags: javascript

This may look as  a common question but I was not able to find an answer for this anywhere.
In my case it's not the felid of the object but the object name which changers dynamically.

when debugged the variable "itemId" get stored with the value "solarPanel" (as intended)
what i was expecting was to get "Solar Panel testing" printed to the console

```
function DataBase (name, price, images, discription, shipping, remaining){
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.images = images;
  this.discription = discription;
  this.shipping = shipping;
  this.remaining = remaining;
} 

let solarPanel = new DataBase("Solar Panel testing", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let solarLight = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let electricScooter = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let windTurbineDom = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let windTurbinePor = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let waterTurbine = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let solarCharger = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let itemEight = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);
let itemNinee = new DataBase("Solar Panel", 400, ["blankItem.png"], "This is a greate item", 50, 10);



let buyBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("itemAddCartBtn");
console.log(buyBtn);
for (let i = 0; i < buyBtn.length; i++){
  buyBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    let itemId = this.parentElement.getAttribute("id");

    // when I debugged the code it got executed as intended up to this point
    //the error occured in the line below

    console.log([itemId].name); //itemId is defined but [itemId].name is undifined
  });
}
```

chat gpt suggested to replace the "console.log([itemId].name);"
with "console.log(window[itemId].name);"
but that did not worked ...
in the both instances the console was printed with the word "undefined"

Comment: `itemId` holds the value of the `id` attribute not the actual `element`. If you want to get the value of the `name` attribute just do `parentElement.getAttribute("name")` .

Comment: my code works fine until the line "console.log([itemId].name);"...
its all about calling the object how to make this happen ? @Izanagi

Comment: `[..].name` is trying to access the property `name` of an array. `window[..]` doesn't work because `let` variables don't become part of `window`. Read the duplicate above. TL;DR: don't use separate variables, use an object instead!

Comment: Thanks very much 
deceze ♦
i tried using the eval() function and it worked as well :)

Comment: I'm very new to JS so i actually have no idea how to make this happen using separate variables...

Comment: Don't `eval`. **DO NOT `eval`!!** Again, use an object to begin with instead of separate variables: `let data = { solarPanel: ..., ... }; data[itemId]`!